# One or two lines of output?

Tags: java, printing, println

Suppose I executed the following Java method:

```
public static void print() {
    System.out.print("This is some text");
    System.out.println();
}
```

How many lines of output are printed? What counts as a "line of output"? I would think there are two, but I really don't know.

Comment: Why not execute & see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be one line of output printed because `System.out.print("This is some text")` does not automatically move the cursor to a new line, but `System.out.println()` without arguments simply prints a new line, so the overall effect is the same as that of `System.out.println("This is some text")`, i.e. one line of output.

You can read more about this by looking at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) for the `PrintStream` class.

Answer (score 0):

one line

System.out.print("This is some text"); <-- this is output with no new line

System.out.println(); <-- this prints a newline

You would define a "line of output" as anything output up to a newline (including the cursor)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print("text")
```

print "text" on the same line, without append new-line character.

```
System.out.println("text")
```

print "text" on a line and than adds a new-line character (\n)